# Etiquette for adding answer that does not merit existing bounty

Tags: discussion, etiquette, bounty

On more than one occasion, I have had my attention drawn to a question because of an existing bounty and decided to add an answer, even though I know my answer should not be awarded a bounty. Do I need to indicate in such cases that I know the bounty should not go to me? If so, what is the best way of going about this?

(More specific details: In one case, the bounty was designated for [an existing exemplary answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151474/484). In another case, someone else had added a bounty to [an older "showcase" question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151108/484). I took the bounty as a sign that an additional, more thoroughly explained answer would be appreciated; however, I did not believe I ought to receive a bounty for answering my own question in this case.)

Comment: For the first case, I don't think there is any doubt: if the bounty is explicitely meant to go to an existing answer, new answers will not look like they are applying for the bounty. If the bounty is awarded because someone wants a better answer, he is free to choose who to award the bounty too. Maybe the only problem case would be one where you know that your answer does not deserve the bounty, but it looks like it does. Then you can either mention it in a comment, or take the bounty, and reaward it to the answer you think really deserves it.

Comment: don't worry about it:-) If someone wants to give you a bounty (or upvote or downvote) they will do it whatever, making comments in the answer doesn't usually affect it much and the final result doesn't really matter:-)

Comment: Always add an answer if you believe this improves what current answers provide.

Comment: If your answer solves the problem, I would not mind being awarded with the bounty, regardless whether there are (better?) solutions. If your answer is not downvoted, no harm is done.